# Rename a folder with Grunt or Node.JS

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

Is it possible to rename a folder without the whole process of making a new directory, copy files into new directory, then remove the old directory?

This process takes several minutes to complete, I am forced to use a batch script to rename the folders, I'd prefer it all to be handled by Grunt. Looking through the Node docs it appears there is no way to rename folders similar to the way 'mv' or 'rename' commands work.

The use-case is for a faster deployment workflow with Grunt on an intranet site. I'd like minimal down time, 2 minutes of downtime to copy files is not ideal.

- I stage my website on the server in www/test.
- I then rename www/prod to www/archived
- Then rename www/test to www/prod making the new site live.

Answer (score 0):

Using [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) solved my problem, however you have to warn future developers which platform the shell commands are meant for, in my case Windows.

```
shell: {
        options: {
            stderr: false
        },
        'archiveToDelete': {
            command: 'rename <%= yeoman.winserver %>\archived delete-this'
        },
        'liveToArchive': {
            command: 'rename <%= yeoman.winserver %>\prod archived'
        },
        'deployToLive': {
            command: 'rename <%= yeoman.winserver %>\test prod'
        },
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback
which will do a 'mv' equivalent command.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but for this exact same task I prefer to use symbolic links rather than renames:

1. I upload my files as www/20150602-214412 (exact timestamp of the build)
2. I remove existing symlinks www/prod and create new symlink to my timestamped build

That way I have as many archives as I want, and I know exactly when the files were deployed.

In grunt I use `grunt-contrib-symlink` and `grunt-contrib-clean`